# In Lucene how do terms get used in calculating scores, can I override it with a CustomScoreQuery?

Tags: lucene, scoring

Has someone successfully overridden the scoring of documents in a query so that the "relevancy" of a term to the field contents can be determined through one's own function? If so, was it by implementing a [CustomScoreQuery](http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_3_2/api/org/apache/lucene/search/function/CustomScoreQuery.html) and overriding the customScore(int, float, float)? I cannot seem to find a way to build either a custom sort or a custom scorer that can rank exact term matches much higher than other prefix term matches.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know lucene directly, but I can tell you that Solr, an application based on lucene, has got this feature:

[Boosting query via functions](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrRelevancyFAQ#head-f013f5f2811e3ed28b200f326dd686afa491be5e)

Let me know if it helps you.

Comment: I'm accepting this because it's the only answer, it is an answer about Solr though, but it's somewhat helpful.

Comment: Did you find a solution to your problem?